# Plot: color all larger than different color

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

In a plot, how can I color all values above a threshold in a different color? Like everything above mean + std or mean + 2*std ?

Comment: use a [LineCollection](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/dpsanders/matplotlib-examples/blob/master/colorline.ipynb)

Comment: What type of plot are you referring to?  A line (e.g. `ax.plot(...)`), points (e.g. `ax.scatter(...)` or `ax.plot(..., ls='none')`), an image or gridded data (e.g. `imshow`/`pcolormesh`/`pcolor`), or something else?

Comment: The line color of the plot. I know how to set it globally, but how about short segments?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using a [`LineCollection`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multicolored_line.html) is the proper way to go, but you can also do an easy version in one line of code using masked arrays:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# make a weird continuous function
r, t = np.random.random((100,)), np.arange(0, 100, .01)    
y = sum(r[3*i+0]*np.sin(r[3*i+1]*t + 10*r[3*+2]) for i in range(10))

# generate the masked array
mask = ma.masked_less(y, 1.1)

plt.plot(t, y, 'k', linewidth=3)
plt.plot(t, mask, 'r', linewidth=3.2)
plt.show()
```

The cheat here is that it draws over the original data with the filtered data so sometimes the underlying curve can show, depending on how it's rendered.  I made the red line here a bit thicker, but I'm not sure whether it made a difference.  The advantage is that it's basically one line, `ma.masked_less(y, 1.1)`, for a threshold of `1.1`.

The reason masked arrays are needed here is that otherwise there would be a line connecting the different segments, and the mask causes these points to not be plotted.

Comment: See also [this example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/color_by_yvalue.html)