# Change color of lineplot mid-line segment

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-xarray

I need to plot a line plot. I want to plot all parts of the lineplot that are below zero blue, and all parts above red.

Here's what I managed so far:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 40)
y = np.random.random(len(x))-0.5
da = xr.DataArray(y, dims=('x',), coords={'x':x})

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
da.plot(ax=ax, color='red', linewidth=3)
da.where(y<0).plot(ax=ax, color='blue', linewidth=3)
plt.show()
```

Here's what I get with this script:

[image: Picture of what I get. Only line segments that are completely below zero are blue]

But what I want is for the color to change at the threshold of 0, like this example (that I've modified to show what I want):

[image: Picture of what I want. All lines below zero are blue]

I've looked at some suggestions here, for example this here: [Plot: color all larger than different color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27951521/plot-color-all-larger-than-different-color)

But I get the same figure with that solution. It seems that the solution lies in the fact that all their line segments are incredibly short, so you don't notice that a segment that passes the threshold doesn't change color at the threshold, and only the next segment is drawn in a different color.

Is there a straightforward way to do this? Or do I have to separate the line segments that cross the threshold manually?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It seems that the solution lies in the fact that all their line segments are incredibly short, so you don't notice that a segment that passes the threshold doesn't change color at the threshold, and only the next segment is drawn in a different color.

You could just interpolate your data such that this holds true for your data as well.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xx = np.linspace(0, 1, 40)
yy = np.random.random(len(xx))-0.5

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 4000)
y = np.interp(x, xx, yy) # linear piecewise interpolation

da = xr.DataArray(y, dims=('x',), coords={'x':x})
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
da.plot(ax=ax, color='red', linewidth=3)
da.where(y<0).plot(ax=ax, color='blue', linewidth=3)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a good idea, but there are some complications. Of course my data is not two numpy arrays, it's a, xarray dataset, so I'd need to interpolate that. Also, my x-axis is a time dimension, not just an array of floats. I've given you an upvote, but I'd like to see whether someone else comes up with another solution before I accept this as the answer.